# Dragging div element in Edge causes things to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

Fairly minimal example of my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag Issue</title>
<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: gray;
}

div.area {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

div.listbox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}

div.item {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    font-family: Arial, Hevetical, sans-serif;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="area" style="left:0%;top:0%;width:65%;height:33%;background:red">TEXT</div>
<div class="area" style="left:0%;top:33%;width:65%;height:33%;background:white">TEXT</div>
<div class="area" style="left:0%;top:66%;width:65%;height:34%;background:blue">TEXT</div>

<div class="area" style="left:65%;top:0%;width:35%;height:100%;background:green;padding:1em">
<div class="listbox" style="width:90%;height:80%;max-width:90%;max-height:80%">
<div class="item" draggable="true">abc</div>
<div class="item" draggable="true">def</div>
<div class="item" draggable="true">ghi</div>
<div class="item" draggable="true">jkl</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to be able to drag text fields (the whole text block, not selected text) from the listbox into the other areas.  In Firefox, this works fine, I can drag the item and drop it wherever (obviously does nothing in this example).  In Edge, as soon as I start dragging, all the areas apart from the direct ancestor of the dragged block disappear.

Oh, and get this: if the Javascript console is open, it either doesn't happen, or happens after a delay.

Seems like a bug in Edge (and/or underlying toolkit), but I need a workaround.  It doesn't happen if you drag images, but I need to be able to drag a text block.

Specifics for my case.  Edge and Firefox are the only browsers I need to support, both can be assumed to be pretty recent, but any Javascript-based workaround has to be completely vanilla.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is a chromium issue which has been spotted days ago. For more information, you can check [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370030&sort=-modified%20-opened%20target&q=drag&can=1).

**Workaround:**

Apply following styles to the draggable element. In your example, it should be `div.item`.

```
transform: translate(0, 0);
z-index: 0;
```

**Fix:**

It is stated this issue has been fixed in version 107. I've performed a test in Edge Beta 107, and this issue has been fixed. So, we can expect that Edge Stable 107 will do the same.